# How to determine the names of all installed keyboard layouts?

Tags: winapi, keyboard

To determine the name of the **active** keyboard layout, one can get its "numeric name" by invoking [GetKeyboardLayoutName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646298%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then looking it up under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\{0}\Layout Text`.

However, inexplicably, there appears to be no way to convert the locale identifiers returned by [GetKeyboardLayoutList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646297%28VS.85%29.aspx) into the "numeric names" suitable for lookup in the registry.

Is there any way to retrieve the Layout Text of all installed keyboard layouts *without activating each one* to do so?

For example, for United States-International, `GetKeyboardLayoutList` returns `f0010809` on my system but the name is stored under `00020409` (which can be verified by activating `f0010809` and calling `GetKeyboardLayoutName` - which will return `00020409`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
// Returns KLID string of size KL_NAMELENGTH
// Same as GetKeyboardLayoutName but for any HKL
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values
BOOL GetKLIDFromHKL(HKL hkl, _Out_writes_(KL_NAMELENGTH) LPWSTR pwszKLID)
{
    bool succeded = false;

    if ((HIWORD(hkl) & 0xf000) == 0xf000) // deviceId contains layoutId
    {
        WORD layoutId = HIWORD(hkl) & 0x0fff;

        HKEY key;
        CHECK_EQ(::RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Keyboard Layouts", &key), ERROR_SUCCESS);

        DWORD index = 0;
        while (::RegEnumKeyW(key, index, pwszKLID, KL_NAMELENGTH) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            WCHAR layoutIdBuffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
            DWORD layoutIdBufferSize = sizeof(layoutIdBuffer);
            if (::RegGetValueW(key, pwszKLID, L"Layout Id", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, nullptr, layoutIdBuffer, &layoutIdBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (layoutId == std::stoul(layoutIdBuffer, nullptr, 16))
                {
                    succeded = true;
                    DBGPRINT("Found KLID 0x%ls by layoutId=0x%04x", pwszKLID, layoutId);
                    break;
                }
            }
            ++index;
        }
        CHECK_EQ(::RegCloseKey(key), ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        WORD langId = LOWORD(hkl);

        // deviceId overrides langId if set
        if (HIWORD(hkl) != 0)
            langId = HIWORD(hkl);

        std::swprintf(pwszKLID, KL_NAMELENGTH, L"%08X", langId);
        succeded = true;

        DBGPRINT("Found KLID 0x%ls by langId=0x%04x", pwszKLID, langId);
    }

    return succeded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an API for this. However, the work-around of briefly switching to the layout just to determine its "numeric name" works perfectly, with no noticeable side-effects.

Might not be so good in a multi-threaded app where the user may be typing while this happens though!